# How to remove white thin line between two pages

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working on website.In that I am using Photo Book Gallery plugin for slider purpose.But in slider show's vertical white thin line between two pages.I want to remove that line.
Please help me,if is there any solution.

URL:-http://www.h2interios.com

Answer (score 0):

```
.booklet .b-wrap-right
{
background: none !important
}
```

Add this code in your stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

Add this css in your stylesheet

```
#main-content .container::before{
background-color: transparent;
}
```